# Como posso passar o atributo COUNT na minha string sql, uma vez que "COUNT" é uma palavra reservada do php?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Segue a string de select:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conta WHERE username:usuario AND userpassword:senha";
```

Comment: Está faltando fechar um parênteses no fim do seu código.

Comment: Se o `count` vai estar dentro de uma string não faz diferença se ele é palavra reservada ou não.

Answer (score 0):

O `count(*)` está dentro da string, então não tem problema, para pegar seu valor e ficar mais legível também, sugiro atribuir um alias para ele ex: `select count(*) as total from ...`